# Taylor series for $(1+x)\mathrm{e}^{(x^2-x)}$

Tags: real-analysis, taylor-expansion

I have to find Taylor series about $0$ for $f(x)=(1+x)\mathrm{e}^{(x^2-x)}$. I found the following series representation
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(1+x)(x^2-x)^n}{n!}$$
but I know Taylor series should like $\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n x^n$ and I don't know how to handle that nasty expression with $x$ and make it look like a proper Taylor sequence. Any hints how do I proceed?

Comment: It seems to me you didn't take in account the $1+x$ term. Anyway you can use binomial expansion for $(x-1)^n$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**hint**
$$e^{x^2}=\sum_{i=0}^{+\infty}\frac {x^{2i}}{i!} $$

$$e^{-x}=\sum_{j=0}^{+\infty}\frac {(-x)^j}{j!} $$

$$e^{x^2-x}=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}(\sum_{i=0}^n\frac {(-1)^{2n-i}}{i!(2n-i)!})x^n $$

Answer (score 1):

The Taylor series starts like
$$
1+\frac12x^2+\frac13x^3-\frac18x^4+\frac{11}{30}x^5-\frac{31}{144}x^6+\frac{169}{840}x^7-\frac{641}{5760}x^8
$$
or if you prefer
$$
1\frac{x^0}{0!}+0\frac{x^1}{1!}+1\frac{x^2}{2!}+2\frac{x^3}{3!}-3\frac{x^4}{4!}+44\frac{x^5}{5!}-155\frac{x^6}{6!}+1014\frac{x^7}{7!}-4487\frac{x^8}{8!}
$$
These values do not inspire me any particular nice form for the general term.